# Content_for Javascript not found on Heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm loading a bunch of page specific JS files. They're all working on my local host but on Heroku I get a console error "file not found".

Here is one example of page specific JS for my home page.

home.html.erb

```
<% content_for :landing_js do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "landing.js" %>
<% end %>
```

That file is located in `assets/javascripts/landing.js`

Application.html.erb

```
<%= yield :landing_js %>
```

What is the correct way to route to the file?

Answer (score 0):

The page specific Javascript files don't get compiled with the rest of the assets. You need to precompile them separately. You can do that by adding this line of code to `config/environments/production.rb`

```
# Precompile the page specific JS files.
config.assets.precompile += [ "landing.js", "foo.js", "bar.js" ]
```